# What is the vim counterpart for C-h k, C-h w in Emacs?

Tags: vim, emacs

There are two very useful functions in Emacs:

- C-h k: Input a key sequence, it tells you which command you are
  running(i.e. which command a certain keystroke binds to)
- C-h w: Input    a command, it tells you which keystroke the command
  is bound to.

What is the vim counterpart of these two commands?

Comment: Note: There's an important difference between Emacs and Vim logic in this area. In Emacs, key sequences and commands are separate things. There's a command called `left-char` for moving left by one character, and by default the left arrow key is bound to this command. In Vim, though, commands don't exist as independent entities. The concept of moving left a character has no name in Vim. It has to be referred to by its default key, `h`. You can change your keybindings -- for example, you can make the key `q` move left with `map q h` -- but `q` is bound to `h`, not a command like `left-char`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:help :command
```

shows the documentation for `:command`.

```
:help i_ctrl-a
```

shows the documentation for `<C-a>` in insert mode.

How to use the doc is **the single most important thing** a new vimmer should learn. Seriously.

If you have a problem with a tricky mapping, say `<leader>b`, you can do

```
:verbose map <leader>b
```

to know what it does and where it is defined.

Comment: Also, `:viusage` and `:exusage` give you an overview of every built-in commands and mappings.

Comment: @romainl I get 'Sorry, no help for i_ctrl_c' for the command :help i_ctrl_c. What am I missing?

Comment: Oups, that was a typo, sorry.